# SVG code inside encodeURIComponent not working in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, animation, svg, uri, smil

I'm trying to animate anything inside a encodeURIComponent() in IE.  I know SMIL isn't supported by IE, but it's just so much easier than using pure JS to animate/rotate an svg  tag.  Here is an example of something that works in Firefox and Chrome, but not IE:

```
var uri = encodeURIComponent(
                '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' +
                '<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.0" viewBox="0 0 120 40" xml:space="preserve">' +
                '<script type="text/javascript" xlink:href="http://leunen.me/fakesmile/smil.user.js"/>' +
                    '<circle cx="30" cy="50" r="15" fill="blue" stroke="black" stroke-width="1">' +
                    '<animateMotion path="M 0 0 H 300 Z" dur="8s" repeatCount="indefinite" />' +
                    '</circle>' +
                 '</svg>');
```

You will notice the xlink:href to the FakeSmile that I would think should handle the animation with no problem, since it's not dynamic.  If you try a similar fiddle, you will see it works in IE when inside the  tag:

http://jsfiddle.net/FG3PG/1/

Does this work because of some meta tags or other html code on jsfiddle's end?  Or is it the fact the code I included is wrapped in a encodeURIComponent()?  Ultimately the svg needs to be wrapped or it won't show up at all, regardless of it animating.

Comment: You should provide the demo which works in FireFox and Chrome but does not work in IE. (The working demo you provided is just a sub-part and does not show the problem).

Comment: Why do you need encodeURIComponent? Is it to put the data in an image or background-image? You do know that javascript doesn't run in images don't you?

Comment: @RobertLongson, yes, I know js doesn't run "in images" but it runs if '<script type="text/ecmascript"><![CDATA[...js code...]]>' was included in the uri wouldn't it?

Comment: That depends. What are you doing with the uri variable?

Comment: @RobertLongson, I'm using a private lib that prototypes a shape, defines the markup:'<image class="body">', then calls get image() when updating the attributes of the shape on a canvas where the uri is defined and then returned like: return {'xlink:href': 'data:image/svg+xml,' + uri}.  So, would the encoded uri include something I'm missing?  Do I use CDATA and run js "in the svg" or call a pure js method in the svg's onLoad?  Nothing seems to work, but it works in the fiddle without encoding...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript will not run in image elements.

Browsers with native SMIL will run the animation, but fakesmile is a javascript emulation of SMIL and will not work in an image so your animation does not run in IE.

Comment: I don't understand how that applies to this situation.  I think you're talking about data uris in an <img> tag, like this http://css-tricks.com/data-uris/ which is not the case.  This is about loading svg into the dom?  I know you can't run js from css or an img, but you certainly can run js inside svg like the fiddle I linked to (works in IE), even if it's wrapped in <script> then in CDATA inside the beginning and ending <svg> tags.  The remaining question and factor in this issue is if encoding the uri affects the js in that CDATA tag.  What do you think?

Comment: Based on your final question comment you are using the uri data in an `<image>` element if that's not the case you need to make the question clearer.